# An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected

Tags: pine-script

I wrote this code in `pinescript`:

```
kijen_forw(period ) =>
    kjf = array.new_float(20)
    for i = 1 to period
        array.set(kjf,i,donchian(kijensenPeriods-i))
    kjf
kjf_draw = kijen_forw(10)
plot(kjf_draw , color=color.new(color.yellow,00) , linewidth=2 
,offset=10 , show_last=10 ,title="Kijensen Forward" )
```

But I get this error :
**Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'series'='kjf_draw'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected**

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this easily by simply assinging an array to a variable, for example, arrayex_var = array.get(kjf, len)
plot(arrayex_var, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `kjf` which is an `array`. Then you are trying to plot an array which is not possible. Your function should return a numerical value.